# SQLAlchemy mapped_collection on table itself?

Tags: python, collections, sqlalchemy

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow fetch the objects from a table and get them returned indexed by an arbitrary value, similar to mapped_collection.

I realize that this is easy to work around (And that I am already doing). But I was just wondering if this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

what's wrong with :

```
my_mapping = dict(Session.query(MyClass.somekey, MyClass))
```

?

I do that all the time to make a quick cache of something.